# get_children filter with postmeta

Tags: post-meta

I am doing the following to get all the children associated with a post:

```
    $args = array(
        'order'=> 'ASC',
        'post_parent' => get_the_ID(),
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'task'
    );
    $tasks = get_children( $args );
```

Now the posts of type `task` have postmeta associated with them. One particular meta_key is `task_progress`. I would like to get all the children whose `task_progress` meta_value is less than 100. What is the best way to filter the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
global $wpdb;
$parent = 1; // Make sure it's int (intval() it) as it's not escaped in the query
$posts = $wpdb->get_results(
    "SELECT `post_id` AS `ID`, `meta_value` AS `Progress` FROM {$wpdb->postmeta}
        WHERE `meta_key`='task_progress' AND `meta_value` < 100 AND `ID` IN
            (SELECT `post_id` FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE `post_parent`={$parent})
        ORDER BY `meta_value` DESC, `post_id` DESC;" // Sort descending
);
foreach($posts as $post){
    $progress = $post->Progress;
    $post = get_post($ID = $post->ID);
    // Print here
}
```

*Regards*.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without a direct query?

Comment: Not sure and, if it were, there's too much overhead in the parametrized WP queries. This returns just IDs and Progress. Light data, kind on resources. Usually WP returns Post Objects, very inefficient.